# How to delete a corrupted file on SD Card

Tags: 7.0-nougat, nvidia-shield

I have a NVIDIA Shield Tablet K1 running Android 7.0 and SHIELD tablet software version 5.2(24.29.404.153).

My relatively new SD Card has a file which has been corrupted although I'm not sure exactly how this one file was corrupted when everything else seems fine.

If I access the folder through Windows I can delete the file but it does not actually delete on the tablet. If I browse to the folder through the Android file explorer there is nothing in the folder and deleting the folder fails.

I've tried installing SD maid & ES File Explorer and both apps were unable to delete the file or the folder.

I was able to rename the folder through ADB Shell but if I try to delete it or try and list the file it throws the following errors

```
shieldtablet:/storage/sdcard/BrokenFolder $ ls
ls: ./Noisecontrollers - Pillars Of Creation (Full) [HD].mp3ß▒Ñ­ºíü: No such file or directory

shieldtablet:/storage/sdcard $ rm -rf ./BrokenFolder
rm: ./BrokenFolder/Noisecontrollers - Pillars Of Creation (Full) [HD].mp3ß▒Ñ­ºíü: No such file or directory
rm: ./BrokenFolder: Directory not empty
```

Is there anything else I can try to delete this file short of formatting the hard drive, its a 128gb SD card that is almost full and transferring 128gb over USB 2 is quite slow. It is not rooted and i'd rather not root it if not necessary

Comment: Did you try with `rm -rf ./BrokenFolder`?

Comment: Get a computer, preferrably with a Linux system. You should be able to remove the file on the computer.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yes you can see in the terminal log I posted the result that was thrown when i did rm -rf

"No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Go and get a computer, better if it's running Linux or macOS (OS X). Then you can delete the file with the file manager, or via terminal and commands if you prefer, on the computer.

Android utilizes FUSE (Filesyetem in USErspace) based on `vold`, which often runs into various problems. Yours is just one of them. I'm afraid you can't remove the file simply with your tablet.

Comment: The result in Linux was the same as with windows. The folder showed up as empty and can be deleted, but on the tablet the folder is still there. And if i disconnect and reconnect it, the folder reappears. Good idea though.

Comment: Go run `fsck` (Unix) or `chkdsk.exe` (Windows) on it.