# Trying to delete a folder with Termux

Tags: files, delete, termux, bash

I'm trying to delete a file Android will not let me delete it. Trying to use Termux, I can't seem to find the file. I used termux-setup-storage, and per the instructions entered:

```
cd /storage/sdcard0/FilesAndFolders
```

And get

```
bash: cd: /storage/sdcard0/FilesAndFolders: No such file or directory
```

I'm working with Android 11, and I am a real novice at this. I can't figure out what file path they want. Suggestions?

Even though I'm using:

```
rm -rf [directory name]
```

it still comes back saying the Directory is not empty.
No command I try deletes this file. The file name at the end of the string has a black diamond with a question mark on it.

I tried SD Maid to no avail, Termux didn't work. I'm considering a factory reset as my only option. The file is a .mp4. I tried `*.MP4`, but no luck. I've tried deleting the folder and the file in every way I could find. I traced the file from the tree, sometimes it tells me the file doesn't exist when I can see it in the tree.

Is there any way to delete this file?

Comment: Try `cd storage` followed by `ls` to show you the contents. Probably your folder is in `shared`  ; do `cd shared` and `ls` again to see if you can find the folder. //With a normal file explorer can you tell the path where is it stored?

Comment: Looks like you look at your phone via USB/MTP. The paths you can see there are virtual, they do not exist in file-system.

Comment: Maybe there is a `nomedia` file in that folder. Try deleting it using file explorer and then try to delete the folder `rm - rf`

Comment: See this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205247/131553

Comment: "*The file name at the end of the string has a black diamond with a question mark on it.*" seems to indicate that the file/SD card is corrupted. Perhaps the following Q&A might help: [How to delete a corrupted file on SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185182/44325)

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is incorrect.

- Try one folder at a time from the top and see when it fails.
- Or install a file explorer app to look at what's there.  I use `X-plore`.

I am not associated with it.